# Open Terminal Window Client Side

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Is it possible to open terminal of the client machine for a java based web application.

I know, that I can use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command to execute>");
```

The above code will execute the application at the server side. Is there a way to open the terminal window of client machine. I can get the OS details from "User-Agent" request header. But I am not sure if there is any non applet way of invoking client terminal.

Comment: It's not possible.  Imagine how bad of a security flaw it would be to allow a server command line access of a client.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What are you actually trying to accomplish? (and, by the way, you can't rely on the User-Agent string being true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only non-applet way would be to have the user install an application beforehand.  Your webpage could then trigger it via a [custom protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so).

For example, if your custom protocol was "myapp", clicking a link with this URL...

```
myapp://runexec
```

would trigger your app and pass it the URL "runexec" as a message.  Depending on the message received you could do various things.