# How to subscribe to a custom URL protocol in a .NET app?

Tags: .net, windows, api, url, visual-c++

I want to subscribe to a custom URL protocol, eg. "pdf" meaning when specially crafted links like the below link are clicked, I get an event (windows launches my EXE passing the link args as command line args). I've done this once before in a VC++ app but can't remember how to do this for the life of me.

Eg link:

> pdf://ANY ARGS

Clicking on the above link should launch my EXE with the command line args:

> "ANY ARGS"

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me. Answer by [Erwinus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277284/1294758).

This is the code for a .reg file, when run, registers the "pdf" protocol to launch "YourApp.exe"

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pdf]
@="URL:pdf Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pdf\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\YourApp\\YourApp.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pdf\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pdf\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pdf\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\YourApp\\YourApp.exe\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\" \"%9\""
```