# Chrome opens custom URI only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on web app which uses Chrome browser
On the computer I have setup [custom URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which executes .exe on the local computer.

On the webapp there is a javascript which loads the custom URI every couple of minutes. Something like:

```
$('<iframe/>', {
  src: 'foo://bar',
  class: 'hidden',
}).appendTo("body").remove();
```

So far so good ... everything is working on the first iframe load. I have tested it without the `remove()` , and it is the same. Only the first time it loads the custom URI, after that I have to at least click on the webapp and next time it will load fine. If I keep the browser minimized or not clicking on the application I don`t get the URI loaded.

I checked the network log of chrome and it appears there.

ATM I have solved this with auto clicker which make clicks on the webapp to keep the URI loaded. I am looking for better solution on this. I guess it is some restriction of Chrome.

Also the only option I have is to use Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried other methods of communicating with local programs like web socket?

Comment: I have not. Is it an option, and the only one?

Comment: force loading by adding an unique query, for example with the date: 'foo://bar?_'+(new Date).toString();

Comment: also doesn't work, already tried. I guess loading custom URI works some other way

Comment: Alright, you mean a 'scheme'. You need to register a scheme first before you can use it, Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so/7277284#7277284

Comment: I did this, and it is working fine. But only the first time iframe loads. After that i have at least to click on the page to get it loaded next time

Comment: I guess that the issue is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147509/custom-uri-call-in-browser-does-not-work-twice-in-chrome?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying `setInterval(loadFunc() {}, 1000*60*3)`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this sounds like a performance "thing" from google with weird reasons. Have you tried changing the url to bust a maybe-possible cache?

Suggestion:

```
var counter = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  $('<iframe/>', {
    src: 'foo://bar?cachebuster='+counter,
    class: 'hidden',
  }).appendTo("body").remove();
  counter++;
}, 1000*60*3)
```

or however the scheme is to be expected.

Comment: This is what exactly I do, and it works but only once. On the next time interval I can see in the console that it is loading the scheme but nothing really loads