# force window open in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I guess what I want to do is not possible.

I would like open a new window using javascript, this is easy:

```
popup = window.open('www.google.es', 'titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no, top=0, left=0, type=fullWindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=yes');
```

but I want this new window opens in Internet Explorer whatever the parent was. So, I'm navigating in crhome, and opens the new window in IE.

Is it possible?

Comment: I dont think you can force a user's computer to use a specific browser. Correct me if im wrong but its based on their default program settings.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to start a Windows process from Javascript running in a web page in Firefox or IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29013486/464709)

Comment: And when the user is using OSX, ChromeOS, phones, or Linux? You can not open up IE from another app. If you control the user's computers and can install stuff, you can always look at a custom URI scheme.

Comment: I'm so glad that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around, that is force to open a link in Edge from an IE page, 
window.open("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com");

but it seems that it's not possible to use a similar command to force a link to open in IE.
It can be achieved using javascript and ActiveX (if enabled) but I can't use this in an enterprise environment (too risky)