# Forcing a launcher to be opened with Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser, desktop, launcher

Ok, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881383/can-i-force-a-link-to-open-in-a-specific-browser) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325307/force-window-open-in-internet-explorer) that is not possible, on a gerneral browser, to force a link to be opened in IE.

So my question is: can I do it with a desktop launcher?

Extended question: Can I easily create a desktop launcher on Windows (10, 7 and maybe older versions) that if double clicked opens a specific URL in IE?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write a program that can launch arbitrary processes. It's unclear what problem you need to solve. Launching processes is a solved problem.

Comment: Right, I didn't explain it well. I wanted to know what's the best way to do it, considering that it have to work with Win10 and Win7. A batch script, a compiled program written in some language, or other ways? I'm not familiar with Windows and I need to find a way to do this.

Comment: Hi, is there any update about the issue?

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, I haven't tested your solution yet because the client has paused this work for some days, because they have some problems to solve on other works. As soon as they wiil tell me to restart I'll test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a batch file to run the command to open IE with a specific url. You can create a `.bat` file and put the following code in the file:

```
start iexplore "http://www.bing.com"
```

Double click the `.bat` file, then it will open IE with Bing website.

Result:

[image]