# What happens when HTTP link is pressed

Tags: linux, windows, browser, operating-system

Suppose I open an email MSG and there is a link in the MSG.
If i tap the link the default browser is lunching and the site is loaded...

How does it happen? What are the steps from tapping till the correct browser is lunched? (I'm asking in general... it doesn't matter if it's Windows or Linux or any other operating system).

Comment: Yes, it does matter. Each OS handles it differently.

Comment: I understand that but I'm looking for the steps not for the specific functions or methods that are being called. I just wish to understand the general idea. If the proccess is so diffrent between OS than i don't mind for explnation which is relevant to a specific OS.

Comment: The steps are that the appropriate application is looked up and then run. Anything more detailed is OS-specific.

Comment: the question is how it looks up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scheme+handler

Comment: Kent, please, either describe the practical problem you're solving or specify some narrowing constraints as @ignacio-vazquez-abrams suggested already twice. As as it is now, the question will either get closed as too broad, or you'll obtain some 5 sentence blah blah as an answer. For instance in order to learn what happens on `Windows` when the user issues a `mailto:` shell command, see [Stack Overflow: how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://…)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so) and especially it's `MSDN` links