# Custom URI Scheme and Skype links

Tags: uri, skype

I registered my own URL scheme.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

[how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Link example: oce://10000

IE, firefox, windows explorer handle it fine. Id 10000 is opened correctly in my app.

Is it possible make this links clickable in Skype?
I already find this unanswered support ticket http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Custom-URI-scheme-handlers/td-p/3627869

Comment: Doesn't seems like MS are going to allow custom schemes. All I can suggest, use http protocol links (like `http://oce/10000`) and catch them with simple http webserver, embedded in app...

Answer (score 3):

You can build a redirect page as suggested here: http://www.developerstalk.net/building-a-redirect-page.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is simple redirect.

Use `.htaccess` and `301 redirect` to desired location. That's the most easiest way. Then just let the server deal with everything.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, an application need to launch/execute URIs it doesn't support or recognize with the OS shell. Skype may be ignoring custom URIs as a security precaution. They don't want to launch unknown applications.