# Opening a page in other type Browser Window

Tags: javascript, php

Actually my project is completed and now I want to implement one thing such that , I have created two invoices such that one for booking invoice and one for food invoice. For Booking invoice printing I am using normal printer at modified size of A5 and in case of food invoice I want to use POS printer i.e. for 58mm * 297mm size. Actually I want to set page default for printing automatically as per my page size which I have given to my code and printer must be selected default which is not getting done.  Is it possible to get any solution ?

Otherwise ,  If I am using chrome then is it possible to redirect a page in Mozilla Firefox or any other other kind of browser new window ??  any kind of solution to this will resolve my problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Neither JS or PHP (which has nothing to do with the client) can decide the default printer. That depends on the clients system and browser settings. 2. No, your code can't open a specific application on the clients computer. That would be a massive security hole.

Comment: If your clients are pre-known, you can register new URL scheme to achieve your goal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so