# Open windows form from link in outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

I would please like to find out how I can launch a windows form written in c# from a link in outlook. Changes in my db will send n mail from which my application should be able to open so that the user can upload documents to a shared folder on a server.

Can someone please advise me on this thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can register application with your custom protocol. In example, you can create protocol `myAppProtocol`and associate it with your application (ie. `c:\apps\myApp.exe`). Then, you can send link in mail which looks like `myAppProtocol:something`. When user clicks on that link, it will open your application with passed parameter `something`.

Take a look at following resources:

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

or use [third-party solution](https://customurl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Ok I see now, thank you I will try it this way. Thanx for the help