# Find and Run Application on PC

Tags: javascript, php, html, hta

I try to figure out how to find and run an application on the users pc when you click a button on the website. I saw this feature on the Unity Assets Store Page. When you click there the Add to Downloads Button the Asset will be opened in Unity. Now I try this too. Therefor I searched a bit and find out that you can do this with HTA? But I only found how to run a specific application like notepad but what is when i dont know the application path. How can I do that?

Comment: What when you like *wanna* execute a shutdown, syskey or install some malware? ;p

Comment: I know that the user have to check a checkbox that the user agrees to run it

Comment: this can be done with [custom protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Comment: ok. thanks. i found this: [link](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/04/18/registering-an-application-to-a-uri-scheme-using-net) and did this but i dont really understand how i can run the application then

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that you tried until now and explain more your issue and what did you mean by i dont know the path of your application ?