# How do I open a WPF application from a MVC website button click?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I have been tasked with finding a solution for launching a WPF desktop app from a button click on a running MVC web page hosted on the same client box as the WPF app.  Is this possible?  It is possible with a registry hack, but this method does not provide the running WPF app with sufficient permissions to allow some of its third party dependencies to run properly.  Thanks!

Steven

Comment: One possible way is to have a constantly running application in the user's system tray that connects to your site. When the user clicks a button on the site, it notifies the server, which would in turn notify the application running in the user's system tray, which would launch the WPF app.

Comment: You can register a custom URI handler and redirect to that URI from your application, see [this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so). The up side to this method is you can also pass parameters/information to the application in the URI.