# Windows, Set custom protocol handler name

Tags: windows, registry, protocol-handler

I'm trying to set a name to my protcol handler without touching the executable,
let me explain, when i register a protcol handler [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)
and I try to open it from the browser i get a popup like this:

[image: Popup]

Now chrome and the other browsers get the protocol name from the executable file properties:

[image: Windows Properties]

My question is: there is a windows registry key that let me specify the protcol name, without touching the executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better way is to include application name directly in your protocol definition:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\your-protocol-name\Application]
"ApplicationName"="Your Application Name"
```

Modifying MuiCache (as suggested in previous answer) is tricky - it doesn't always work, e.g. if your handler executable name is ProtocolHandler.exe and there is MS Office installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the *Friendly App Name* in the registry:

in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache` add an entry with name "*PATH\TO\EXE.FriendlyAppName*" and the value will be the name you want to show in the browser pop-up.

---

Add to registry in bat:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache" /f /t "REG_SZ" /v "C:\protocol_handler.exe.FriendlyAppName" /d "App Name"
```