# How to register custom protocol for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, protocols, url-scheme

I want to handle queries like `myscheme://foo` in any browser by my application `myscheme.exe`.

As I understand, solution will depend on version of used operation system. For old OS (until windows 7) it is enough to just save record in registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  myscheme
  (Default) = "URL:Myscheme Protocol"
  URL Protocol = ""
  DefaultIcon
     (Default) = "myscheme.exe,1"
  shell
     open
        command
           (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Myscheme\myscheme.exe" "%1"
```

Unfortunately [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) declares such way as deprecated. And I should not use this API anymore. Recommended version on page goes `microsoft-edge` (it contains no info about it)!!!

So, I started to research it for `windows 8`. I came across [File type and URI associations model](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/w8cookbook/file-type-and-protocol-associations-model) where it says that in `Windows 8` applications are no longer able to programmatically set themselves as the default handler for a file type or URI. As I understand new architecture uses notification system, where users control default application via special prompt. But [Default Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/shell/default-programs) says that it will no longer valid for windows 10 (exploration reference is DEAD!).

So, how to properly handle custom protocols in windows 10? Unfortunately Windows has just awful documentation. And what about different versions of OS? I should use different techniques for different versions?

P.S. Please, don't mark this question as duplicate. Other questions like [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/), [How do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/) propose deprecated solutions.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It's still the way that works in Windows 10.  So if your application needs to also run in 7 it is what you should use.  For the Windows API and registry, "deprecated" methods have been supported for decades and usually keep working ... until they don't.  Use it now, change it for Windows 11 if needed.

Comment: Adding to the above correct comment, deprecation in Windows is far less likely to result in removal due to the fact that thousands of programs rely on an API.

Comment: This still works on Windows 10 Enterprise.