# External link to open a scene in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to open Unity application through a link from a PDF or something? Like, when the user clicks on the link, the Unity app opens and then shows the image to which the user has clicked the link for.
Similarly, 3 different links are kept and each link opens the same Unity application but shows different images.

I am looking to program this in .exe and .apk. Which is why I wanted to know if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to mention a more general case first.

As you likely know, if you have an .exe which you want to run with additional data, this can be done using command-line arguments: in your case, one that determines which fixed "image" you want to show. User Taylor-Libonati on the Unity Answers forum [has provided a snippet](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1247226/view.html) as a suggestion for reading command-line args in Unity.

However, you wish to run the application through a link. The cleanest way to do this would be to use a custom *URL scheme* -- define a custom protocol that launches your app upon a click. For Android, [an example can be found on the Unity Answers forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/490404/how-do-i-launch-my-unity-game-from-a-url-in-androi.html) by the user Cake.

For Windows, [you'll have to tamper with the Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389223/668143) as shown in James Gregory's answer to a similar question. (Or look into "pluggable protocol handlers", but I have no idea what those are.)

In both cases, you'll need to intercept the data from the link. [This tutorial](https://www.joe0.com/2019/01/27/how-create-a-custom-browser-uri-scheme-and-c-protocol-handler-client-that-supports-opening-and-editing-of-remotely-hosted-documents-through-webdav/) (which isn't quite what you're looking for but should be a good guideline) suggests that in a Windows environment, the link might be passed as the first command-line argument, which we know we can read. I'd suggest experimentation.

Alas, I'm afraid I don't know how you'd intercept this for Android. I've never deployed anything made with Unity to that platform.

Hopefully you'll be able to implement something based on these considerations though.

Comment: Thank you. I used Command Line Arguments to pass arguments to Unity application.