# Launching an Application using JavaScript, similar to Zoom

Tags: javascript

I've read the other SO questions about launching an application using JavaScript, and from what I've read it seems impossible unless one is using an outdated version of IE.

However, I notice that whenever I enter a Zoom meeting, Zoom prompts the user, "Do you want to open Zoom?" And if one clicks "yes", then the Zoom application opens. This works on all browsers, at least to my understanding.

How is this done? Is it done by using something other than JavaScript?

Comment: Zoom installs a tiny webserver on the user's computer. Clicking the link triggers a request to a `localhost` URL, and their server opens the application. This created quite a buzz when it was discovered because on Macs at least, the server kept running after "uninstalling" Zoom, and your machine would auto-join meetings with mic and cam enabled.

Comment: @ChrisG This is interesting, as I had always assumed it was simply a custom URL scheme. Do you have a source for this? Would love to read more on how they're accomplishing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Comment: @esqew Here's the article: https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/zoom-zero-day-4-million-webcams-maybe-an-rce-just-get-them-to-visit-your-website-ac75c83f4ef5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually has nothing to do with JavaScript.

It is using a custom protocol registered on the machine at the time the program is installed.

Basically, they register some custom protocol (like `zoom://`) with the OS itself at the time of installing the program. Then, all you have to do to launch it is navigate to a URL like `zoom://meeting1234`. The OS will see this custom protocol and launch the appropriately registered program.

Here is some documentation:

- Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration
- Mac: https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x

Comment: As an extra note, on mobile devices when you get a popup like when you visit Reddit about launching in their app or continue with Chrome, that is metadata placed on Reddit that the mobile browsers are responding to which is a similar idea but slightly different implementation.

Comment: what about Linux?

Comment: Not sure, but googling "linux custom url protocol" will probably get you some answers.

Comment: Thanks. For future visitors: create a .desktop file with `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/MYPROTOCOL;`.