# How does Zoom launch their desktop app from Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How does Zoom's website launch Zoom Meetings from Google Chrome?
Can I do it using JavaScript? If so, how can I do it?
[Confirmation dialog box (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKxju.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not done with JavaScript, but with plain HTML. The way it works is, you create an `<a>` with an `href` attribute with a protocol *other* than the ones a browser usually recognizes - that is, other than `http`, `https`, etc.

If the user has installed an application that recognizes the protocol, the browser will try to open that application.

Similarly to Zoom, for IRC links, you can see something like:

```html
<a href="irc:(IRC INFO HERE)">Link</a>
```

If you click on that link, and your machine has software installed that recognizes the `irc` protocol, that application can be opened directly by clicking on the link (possibly asking you if you want to open it first).

There are lots of different protocols for many different applications. They're quite handy for getting info on a web browser to an application on the user's computer.

For Zoom in particular, there's documentation on how to use its  protocols here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200415164102/https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/guides/client-url-schemes

Comment: So does Zoom Meetings register a custom URL protocol in Windows when a user installs it?

Comment: Yes. If you click on a zoom link and you don't have Zoom installed, your browser will tell you that it doesn't recognize the protocol you clicked, and will ask you if you want to try to select an application from your computer to open it with.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know apps could register custom protocols. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CertainPerformance just one more question: is there a folder/file (or something like that) where those custom protocols are stored in Windows?

Comment: @GabrielPanequeDidi Yes, they're stored in the registry. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Answer (score 0):

Making a link with a protocol registered to the zoom app on the operating system.