# Monitor a Custom Url Protocol Messages - Delphi

Tags: delphi, url, protocols

Have someone an example showing how I handle custom URL protocol from a webpage in my desktop-app like zoom (You got an link and this open the meeting in the desktop-app)?

I'll be happy if some one has nice example or something he can share for the purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so); also this is unbound to Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of registry keys. Look at the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

The code below can create it for you:

```
function RegisterURLProtocol(
    const ProtocolID   : String;
    const ProtocolName : String;
    const DefaultIcon  : String;
    const OpenCommand  : String) : Boolean;
var
    Reg : TRegistry;
begin
    Result := FALSE;
    Reg    := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
    try
        Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
        if not Reg.OpenKey(ProtocolID, TRUE) then
            Exit;

        Reg.WriteString('', 'URL:' + ProtocolName);
        Reg.WriteString('URL Protocol', '');

        if Reg.OpenKey('DefaultIcon', True) then begin
            Reg.WriteString('', DefaultIcon);
        end;
        Reg.CloseKey;

        if not Reg.OpenKey(ProtocolID + '\shell\open\command', True) then
            Exit;

        Reg.WriteString('', OpenCommand);
        Result := TRUE;
    finally
        FreeAndNil(Reg);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Result` be initialized to false instead of true?

Comment: Also two more `Reg.CloseKey()` would be fine to clean up each `Reg.OpenKey()`.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick A matter of taste. In the context of the application I extracted this code, the intent is to continue even if the function fails (Lack of permission for example).

Comment: @AmigoJack No need to cleanup since the Reg object is freed and CloseKey is called by destructor.

Comment: As a stand-alone general-purpose library function, it is not a matter of taste. As it is now, the function always returns `True`, so that's what you'd write in its documentation. Not very useful, though. If the caller wants to continue on failure, just don't stop on the function's returning `False`!

Comment: Edited to return FALSE in case of error.