# URL-Protocoll registration - It doesnt recognize any parameters

Tags: c#, windows, url, registry, protocols

Hi I just tried to register my own URL-Protocoll and read through this Thread
**[How do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)**

It kind of works, but my application doesn't receive any parameters.
For example

"Webly://www.google.de" opens my webly.exe, but it doesn't add the parameter [www.google.de](http://www.google.de)

This is my webly.reg, which registers the protocoll

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp]
@="URL:Webly"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Webly\\Webly.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YourApp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Webly\\Webly.exe\" \"%1\"
```

This is my C#-Code, which reads the parameter

```
 public Main(string[] args = null)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


           
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(arg.ToString());
               
            }
}
```

As you can see, i try to display the argument in a message-box.
Sadly its empty.

Comment: I forgot to mention, i'm using windows 10