# Programatically invoking the default application for a filetype

Tags: windows, file, handler

On a related note to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796748/how-can-i-add-a-custom-url-handler-on-windows-like-itunes-itms), say I've got an file with an handler defined, how would I programatically invoke the registered handler? Don't necessarily need the actual code to do this, just a pointer to some docs or the terminology to google for this.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficent to start a new process specifying the file you want to open with the default application - the rest is handled by Windows. In C# this is done as follows.

```
Process.Start("Foo.jpg");
```

This will open the image using the default application for JPEG images.

Comment: Nice and easy - think I might take this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) function and its advanced cousin, [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: ShellExecute/Ex() is higher level then its lower-level cousins, FindExecutable() and CreateProcess...().  ShellExecute/Ex() is what the Shell uses in the `Start Menu | Run` field and when double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer.