# launching a Windows app on client side (triggered by click on webpage)

Tags: url, registry, protocols, launch

is that possible to launch a preinstalled application from a webpage.

i can see that steam has created its own protocol steam:// by installing something into my registry and now whenever i click a steam://ip link .. it tries to launch a file. so i was wondering if its possible to launch an application from a webpage, may be register an application to a URL protocol?

example: lets say i have link to a media file on my webpage(lets say divx). now one choice is divx webplayer or other choices. but i want that given a choice the user can launch vlc directly by clicking a link (vlc:// http://...), is that possible?

i read a little about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx)
but it doesnt clicks clearly to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: you would need to build/register a URL handler and tie it to the right application. The simplest explanation is previously answered at [How can I add a custom url handler on Windows. Like iTunes itms://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796748/how-can-i-add-a-custom-url-handler-on-windows-like-itunes-itms).

More complex URL handlers will require you to do native code of your very own: the document you linked to is completely correct. You will need some familiarity with writing registry files, but otherwise it is quite doable.