# firefox 5 and protocol file:// on http

Tags: security, xul, gecko, firefox-5, file-uri

in firefox 3, we could open  file:/// in a web page (http://myserver.com/mypage.html).
 With that, we design a firefox Extension for open external application with a specific protocol. (like calc:// for open a link in calc program )

Now, we would use it on firefox 5, but the Gecko 2.0 refuse that. When i try to open a link, i have this backtrace in cosole :

> Security Error: Content at http ://myserver.com/mypage.html may not load or link to file:///C:/test.odf.

It's Normal. Firefox 4 & 5 don't support this :

> Firefox 4 
>   Support for remote XUL has long been a potential security concern; support for it was disabled in Gecko 2.0. This also means you can't load XUL using file:// URLs unless you set the preference dom.allow_XUL_XBL_for_file to true. However, there is a whitelist that lets you specify sites that can still use remote XUL. The Remote XUL Manager extension lets you manage this whitelist.

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_remote_xul

i try to use remote XUL manager : it doesn't work. 
Same problem with adding dom.allow_XUL_XBL_for_file in about:config

I read this bugtracker https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595397 and my bug should not be.

This doesn't work on Firefox 4,5 under windows XP or 7.

I don't now where i can't find some information,

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've answered, as best I can, but I can't make out, in your 'question,' the question you're actually **asking**...could you clarify that for me?

Comment: Remote XUL has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that web pages aren't allowed to link to file:// addresses, it's a different change. In other words, everything you quote and link to after the words "It's Normal" is unrelated and misleading.

Comment: @David : i want to open file:// and custom protocol in firefox 5. We design an extension in firefox 3, but don't work in firefox 4 and 5. I was thinking Remote XUL change is the problem, but not apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to local files was disallowed from remote files in the name of security; this safety check can be overridden by the user (but not without explicit user action).

1. First, the user can install [Local Link (Firefox extension)](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/281), or
2. Secondly, by disabling the security check (this is a little too detailed to post here, so I'll link to the Mozilla knowledgebase for this: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work).

As regards the `calc://` protocol, I'm not sure why that's not handled automatically, but to set up a custom URL handler (on Windows), you can use the command-line:

```
ftype calc # view current binding
ftype calc=\path\to\calcProgram.exe %1
```

References:

- [Links to local pages don't work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work).
- [How can I add a custom url handler on Windows. Like iTunes itms://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796748/how-can-i-add-a-custom-url-handler-on-windows-like-itunes-itms)

Comment: thanks for your answer.

I have the same problem with Local Link ( with or without my personnal extension), and i  use the user_pref on my personal user.js, but nothing happend.

I've try too : 
 - Setting security.checkloaduri to false
 - Setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false

Comment: @Gaetantri: LocalLink allows opening file:// **links** via context menu (stated on its homepage) - it won't help in your case. And if you read the Mozillazine Knowledgebase article - `security.checkloaduri` preference has been removed long ago (in Firefox 1.5 actually). `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` is again something entirely unrelated. You should try it with the `capability.policy.` prefs - I'm not sure whether they still work but they *could*.

Comment: i've try to create capability.policy in my user.js, but nothing appends. this problem starts with firefox 4.