# c++ how to listen HTTP requests

Tags: c++, http

Im new in C++.

I need to listen HTTP requests.

Please advice me some good tutorials or examples

Thanks

update:

Platform: Windows
Language: C++

I will explain more clearly what i need

when user clicks row on this page: `http://ucp-anticheat.org/monitor.html` applications is automatically starts on client machine.

I want to make same thing.

I think on client side is service which listens http requests and if url starts with steam:// service automatically runs application...

Do i need to listen http requests?

What is best solution for my problem?

Comment: Use [The Source](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24), Luke!

Comment: Q: Does it have to be C++?  What about C?  Or Java, Python, C#, etc etc?  Q: What platform? windows?  Linux? Q: What's the application/what are the requirements for this "embedded web server"?  Q: Have you looked at the [Boost Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)?

Comment: To be fair, working with the boost libraries is not a simple task when you are beginning with C++. Correctly handling HTTP-Requests is not a simple task either.

Comment: Using the Boost libraries is somewhat akin to being in heaven...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get your question right, you want to be able to launch an application when someone clicks a link with a custom protocol, like steam:// or telnet://. You are looking for an [Protocol Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A simple way to register such an application is using the ftype program, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796748/how-can-i-add-a-custom-url-handler-on-windows-like-itunes-itms).

Comment: I should up-vote your answer, but it little different from the question title, I was looking for similar solution, I thought using http link & http server to direct link for web page     (e.g YouTube video download), your suggesting were more suitable for me, to create connection between web-browser and external command(I need it for Linux BTW)

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to http requests through a web server like mongoose , which can be easily used in C++ http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ , and  here is a good example of using mongoose web server http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/source/browse/examples/hello.c

I m not sure what you mean 'client side', if you are meaning Browser as your client, you can't control nothing outside your browser. If you want to control a machine, you need your client machine to run your exe, that has the code to act based on your server instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a simple server program, create a SOCKET listening on default http, https etc, ports. Usually we do it inside a loop (at each one you make a read).

Now... would be easer if you specified if you are on Unix like OS or Windows, but from now on you can google it. Like sys/socket.h or try "man 7 socket" on almost all linux (at least the ones I know).

If you want to sniff something you can google some specific apps around web.