# Have activex serve and store executable to a known location

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, activex, executable

I have a web application that runs internally. I need to run an executable (command line application written in C#) from the browser by passing it 2 parameters.

Infrastructure:

- Windows XP - 8
- Internet Explorer 6+
- C# (.Net 4.0)

The code the launches the executable:

```
var scanApp = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
scanApp.run("C:\\Path\\To\\exe param1 param2", 1, true);
```

The above works on my local machine because I have the exe in a known location (on my desktop).

My question is, how best can I deploy this on a client machine through activex and then run the executable?

The workflow would be:

```
1. Go to webpage
2. Click link that attempts to launch exe
3. Activex 'installs/downloads' the exe to a known location if its not there already
4. Run the exe
```

**TLDR**

How to deploy an executable through ActiveX and then launch it whenever user clicks on a webpage button?

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary that the *installation* occur through ActiveX? If not and you can deploy a different way (Group Policy, ClickOnce, etc), you can register a protocol handler to accomplish your second goal (similar to how iTunes is registered as a handler for itunes:// links). Just make that part of the install script.

For more information on that topic, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796748/how-can-i-add-a-custom-url-handler-on-windows-like-itunes-itms) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/10/19/register-a-custom-url-protocol-handler.aspx).

Comment: To clarify, by install I really mean just put the exe somewhere on the client pc. The exe is strictly a command line utility that does some stuff on the client computer and then posts some data to a server. I would like to make it as easy to run from any client within the network.