# CMD / Batch / Registry - String replace not working as expected?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, registry

I'm having the most fun trying to replace a substring in one line of code for a windows registry key

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\ping.exe %1 -t"
```

**Scenario and Context:**

The context is a custom url protocol that will open up a shell with continuous ping to a specific ip and i want to remove the protocol `ping://` from the uri that gets passed as `%1`.
sure i could use a batch file, but I'd prefer to have it all in one line in the registry

**What I've tried:**

so far I've tried appending a list of commands with `&` setting a var and then echoing it..

tried `call set remove=ping://` `&` `call set mynewvar=%1:%remove=%` `&` `ping.exe %mynewvar% -t`

I've tried expanding the variables a few times using `%%`

Basically I've been getting weird results or the replace not working at all

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Typing this, I've started to think I'm overlooking the fact its in string var `@="..."`

thanks

**Registry Key**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING]
@="url:ping protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k set var=%1 & call set var=%%var:ping://=%% & ping.exe %var% -t"
```

**browser typed in url**
`ping://8.8.8.8`

**cmd prompt output**
`Ping request could not find host ping://8.8.8.8/ar. Please check the name and try again.`

I notice the `ar` after the ip is from `%var%` it appears its using the `%v` not `%var`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.. `%v` is actually

`%v – For verbs that are none implies all. If there is no parameter passed this is the working directory.`

got that from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/473602)

**Working code**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING]
@="url:ping protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k set myvar=%1 & call set myvar=%%myvar:ping:=%% & call set myvar=%%myvar:/=%% & call ping.exe %%myvar%% -t"
```

Comment: Nice, but `%var%` also works on my XP system, so `%v` seems not to be the cause for the problem

Comment: I had to remove only `protocol:`, and execute a non-cmd program, so I went with something like this: `"cmd /k set myvar=%1 & call set myvar=%%myvar:protocol:=%% & call \"C:\\Program Files\\path\\to\\program.exe\" \"%%myvar%%\" & exit"`

Answer (score 1):

String replace is only possible with variables not with parameters like `%1`.

Something like this could be a starting point

```
set "var=%1" & call var=%%var:ping://=%%
```

In the registry it could look like

```
...
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PING\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k ( set \"var=%1\" & call set var=%%var:ping://=%% & call set var=%%var:/=%% & call ping.exe %%var%% -t)"
```

Comment: I've gotten it to run in a batch file using `cmd /k "set var=%1 & call set var=%%var:ping://=%% & ping.exe %var% -t"` but no luck with the registry key..

Comment: @StrikeForceZero You should show the full code, you used to get the registry key and how do you try to modify it

Comment: I added it to the question