# Open Youtube links in external videoplayer from browser

Tags: youtube, video-player, uri-scheme

I use videoplayer "PotPlayer". Player can play video from youtube.
For e.g. player can start play youtube video if you run player as:

```
"C:\PotPlayer\PotPlayer.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*******"
```

I added URI Scheme to registry with name "potplayer":

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer]
@="\"URL:potplayer protocol\""
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open\command]
@="c:\\potplayer\\potplayer.exe"
```

And I try open youtube videos in PotPlayer from web-browsers using next link:

```
potplayer://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*******
```

But it just only start Player without transfer the link to player (".../PotPlayer.exe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*******").

How can I transfer the link to PotPlayer using URI Scheme? What I need to change in the registry code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way from [CMD / Batch / Registry - String replace not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334946/cmd-batch-registry-string-replace-not-working-as-expected)

So:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k ( set \"var=%1\" & call set var=%%var:potplayer://=%% & call C:\\PotPlayer\\PotPlayer.exe %%var%%)"
```

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this, and I can't get it to work. I have the 32 bit version (which is at "C:\Program Files (x86)\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini.exe"), what do I need to edit to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Modern potplayer version compatible:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\potplayer\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c ( set \"var=%1\" & set \"var=%%var:~12%%\" & start \"\" \"C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe\" \"%var%\")"