# How to access C:\Program Files\... path of client PC in Asp.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, teamviewer

I have an Asp.NET web application. I can call and run Teamviewer in my application when running on local.

I have a class for call and run TeamViewer.

```
class CallTeamViewer {      
    public static string TeamViewerPath = "";
    public static void FindTeamViewerPath ()  {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version7\teamviewer.exe")) {  
            TeamViewerPath = @"C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version7\teamviewer.exe";
        }
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\TeamViewer\Version8\teamviewer.exe")){ 
            TeamViewerPath = @"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\TeamViewer\Version8\teamviewer.exe";
        }
    }
    public static void ConnectAndRunTeamViewer(string TamViewerId, string TeamViewerPass) {
        CallTeamViewer.FindTeamViewerPath();
        if(TeamViewerPath.Length > 0) { 
            string parameter;
            parameter = " -i " + TamViewerId+ " --Password " + TeamViewerPass+ "";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TeamViewerPath,parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 textboxes and 1 button on aspx page

Connect.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CallTeamViewer.ConnectAndRunTeamViewer(txtTeamviewerID.Text,txtTeamviewerPass.Text); 
}
```

This class works on local. It can find the path of Teamviewer in my computer.

My question: How can I change my class to find path of Teamviewer of client user?

Comment: Consider, just for a moment, what a terrifying place the internet would be if any random website could launch any executables they wanted to from your hard drive.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think such place was called IE6

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be misunderstanding of how web works :) You need to run something on client side - not on server side. ASP.NET executes just on server side (and passes back just html markup that is interpreted by browser). For this kind of work you need a thick client - see @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment regarding security - LOL btw. Since you're already in .NET world, I recommend using ClickOnce (.NET technology that allows you to install applications from web url with just one click - provided your clients have .NET framework installed) and make small app that will do the "thick client" job for you.

Comment: You need to run something on client side - not on server side.-My question : How can I change my class for find path of Teamviewer of client user ?

Answer (score 1):

This *is* possible, but you still need to run an executable or a .reg file on the client's machine to register a protocol handler.

Those kinds of applications (e.g., uTorrent and magnet links, etc), usually define a URI scheme and register a protocol handler on the client's computer.

For example, this is a sample URI for a magnet link:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:sha1:YNCKHTQCWBTRNJIV4WNAE52SJUQCZO5C
```

Then, your ASP.NET application can redirect the user to a URI like that, and the OS will notice that there's a protocol associated to that URI and ask the user if he wants to launch that application.

See:

1. [Creation of link to launch TeamViewer](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php/Plugins:TeamViewer#Creation_of_link_to_launch_TeamViewer)
2. [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. [How can I add a custom url handler on Windows. Like iTunes itms://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796748/how-can-i-add-a-custom-url-handler-on-windows-like-itunes-itms)

Answer (score 0):

I would make some settings page for the user, that she/he could add a path of TeamViewer into the cookies/database. Hope it helps!