# Is there any way for dos command of client user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd, teamviewer

How can I run this line on dos command of client user ?

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version8\teamviewer.exe" -i 125486 --Password 123456
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Get them to type it in?

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: There kind of is a way to do this. Applications like uTorrent do it. Check the answer I've posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24362765/857807).

Answer (score 0):

you mean you have a web site and you want to run this executable from the browser on the client machine?
If this is the case, this is not possible. That would be very dangerous

Comment: I am searching alternative ways for my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327664/how-to-access-c-program-files-path-of-client-pc-in-asp-net-c

Comment: @user3107343 there *is no way*.

Comment: @spender There is a way, using protocols. But he'll still need to run an executable on the client's machine.

Comment: @dcastro launch with passwords? that's rather dangerous

Comment: @spender yeah, i would just have the protocol handler launch the teamviewer exe, and then let the user enter his username/password.

Comment: I have a web application (asp.net c#).There are 1200 computers name in my gridview.I can execute teamviewer and connect to any computer when application running on local. But it is not working on web host!