# Is it possible to run exe file with silverlight c# or javascript on client side?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, exe

Is it possible to run a .exe file on client side with Silverlight.

Or with javascript or something other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no - it would be a huge security hole.

It might be possible for specific browser using plug-ins or ActiveX components (in Internet Explorer) that add such a feature - that will leave the browser very exposed though.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791511/run-exe-from-client-side) - one of the answers there suggest a clever trick if you want to start from the browser an application that you have control over: have the application installer associate a file extension with its EXE, and then you download from the browser a dummy file with that extension.

Comment: So it possible with chrome or FF plugins?

Comment: Yes - maybe there is already something available, otherwise it is surely possible to write such a plug-in. See also the piece I added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean from the context of a remote domain, most definitely not. Think of the ease with which you might deliver a virus by such a mechanism.

Comment: Yes it would be easy. So can you advice what can i do? I want to make button my web site when user clicks it i want to run process(game). Does it possible without creating new application for clients?

Comment: You'd need to persuade your users to install a browser plugin to get this to work, or try to get them to allow elevated permissions for a Java applet. Neither seems like such a great idea.

Comment: So it possible with chrome or FF plugins

Answer (score 0):

Yes, But not seemlessly and not cross browser
Browsers are specifically designed to prvent this sort of thing but....

You can do it in internet explorer through activex javascript

```
function runApp() 
{ 
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell"); 
    shell.run("notepad.exe", 1, True); 
}
```

You might be able to do it via plugin with firefox and chrome, but I don't know and I wouldn't be surprised if you can't