# Search for an email in MS Outlook using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, outlook

If I have the email address and assuming the company employee has outlook installed, how could I write some javascript to open a list of all emails sent by the same sender.

Essentially they would click on a person name on a web page and it would launch Outlook with the view of showing all emails sent by this sender. (Would look identical as if they did it from Outlook)

Comment: Probably not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1791511/532498