# Is it possible to run an .exe or .bat file on 'onclick' in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to run bat/executable file using html5 button event? In IE its achievable using  Shell object if I am not wrong.

Comment: See this link [How to execute a Local File using HTML Application?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113678/How-to-execute-a-Local-File-using-HTML-Application)

Comment: @coolprarun I also confirmed that the link you provide works in my environment (`Win8.1`, `IE11`. Not on `FF27`). You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's what I did. I wanted a HTML page setup on our network so I wouldn't have to navigate to various folders to install or upgrade our apps. So what I did was setup a .bat file on our "shared" drive that everyone has access to, in that .bat file I had this code:

```
start /d "\\server\Software\" setup.exe
```

The HTML code was:

```
<input type="button" value="Launch Installer" onclick="window.open('file:///S:Test/Test.bat')" />
```

(make sure your slashes are correct, I had them the other way and it didn't work)

I preferred to launch the EXE directly but that wasn't possible, but the .bat file allowed me around that. Wish it worked in FF or Chrome, but only IE.

Comment: Dear @Chuff what about if the bat file has a registration command, I mean sth like `REG ADD "HKCU\Software\..."`

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox, Edge and Chrome anymore! Only IE works.

Comment: @Tivi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser

Answer (score 39):

No, that would be a **huge** security breach. Imagine if someone could run

```
format c:
```

whenever you visted their website.

Answer (score 17):

It is possible when the page itself is opened via a `file:///` path.

```
<button onclick="window.open('file:///C:/Windows/notepad.exe')">
    Launch notepad
</button>
```

However, the moment you put it on a webserver (even if you access it via `http://localhost/`), you will get an error:

> Error: Access to 'file:///C:/Windows/notepad.exe' from script denied

Comment: +1 I just confirmed that this works on IE11, but does not on Firefox 27 on Win8.1.

Comment: @IsaacS I don't have access to a Windows 8 box so unfortunately I can't help with that. I've just tried this again with Firefox 28 on Windows 7 and it works, so the additional security is probably limited to Windows 8.

Comment: This allows to "download" notepad.exe, not run it. Firefox 31, Windows 7

Comment: @nodiscc Indeed, Firefox by default does not allow you to run executables, but it's not uncommon to have an extension like [OpenDownload²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload-10902/) to allow you to do so.

Comment: @Stijn the file that gets executed in this case is the file you just "downloaded", not the original. So in most cases it does not work - it doesn't allow you to run programs already installed on your machine.

Comment: @nodiscc correct, it doesn't execute from the original application but from the cache. If it works or not depends on the executable needing access to other files in its directory. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it on Internet explorer with OCX component and on chrome browser using a chrome extension
[chrome document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage)
in any case need additional settings on the client system!

Important part of chrome extension source:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("your.app.id"); 
      port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage); 
      port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
      port.postMessage("send some data to STDIO");
```

permission file:

```
{
      "name": "your.app.id",
      "description": "Name of your extension",
      "path": "myapp.exe",
      "type": "stdio",
      "allowed_origins": [
            "chrome-extension://IDOFYOUREXTENSION_lokldaeplkmh/"
      ]
}
```

and windows registry settings:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\your.app.id
REG_EXPAND_SZ : c:\permissionsettings.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not run/execute an .exe file that is in the users local machine or through a site. The user must first download the exe file and then run the executable file.
 So there is no possible way

The following code works only when the EXE is Present in the User's Machine.

`<a href = "C:\folder_name\program.exe">`

Comment: Dear @coolprarun if I have a bat file in user's machine, How can I run the bat file in chrome using javascript or sth else? I could do it in IE browser through ActiveXObject, However this object is not applicable for chrome.

Comment: Sure you can. With custom URL protocol -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/how-to-launch-an-application-from-a-browser