# Calling the Windows Dial-Tool from browser

Tags: javascript, php, windows

I've been browsing the web, but couldn't find any suiting answer to my question.
I am looking for a way to make a phone number clickable in the browser, the click event should trigger the Windows Dialprogramm.

The reason behind this is, I am close to finishing a company client management software in the internal network and one of few tests left would be the direct click dial up call - thing.

I thank you for any kind of help

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html

Comment: See [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)