# How to open a .exe file in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am newbie to `AngularJS`. Currently I am trying to implement file reading through AngularJS. I can upload `.txt` file and show the data in content which is working fine.

```
Example
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/6aG4x/)

How can I open `notepad.exe` and show content by Using AngularJS ?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html)

Comment: Open notepad.exe? What for? To show content? Why not show it on the page itself?

Comment: No, In my application Uploaded file content be more and I need to open more than one file. do some compare.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, web pages can read files from the file system in a very restricted way: there must be an `<input type="file">` on the page, the user must activate it, and they must select file(s) in some platform specific manner. These restrictions exist for obvious security reasons. A page cannot arbitrarily read a file given a path.

Once the user has selected one or more files, you can read the `files` property from the `input` element, and get an array of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects. Instantiate a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object with the `File`, and use one of the methods there to read the file, such as [`readAsBinaryString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString).

MDN has [a pretty good overview](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Using_files_from_web_applications.html) of accessing files from web applications. It goes into more detail about handling things like drag and drop.

If you are using this in an AngularJS application, you will probably want to wrap it up in a service.

I did a quick search, I'm sure there are several available FileReader wrappers for Angular available on google, [for example](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/03/building-a-filereader-service-for-angularjs-the-service.aspx), or [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).