# Downloading and executing an exe through javascript

Tags: javascript, powershell

I want to download and execute an exe using javascript. I have tried to do this through windows powershell but haven't succeeded to execute powershell code from javascript. Any help is appreciated

Comment: WSH is likely more useful

Comment: See the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html It may help you

Comment: "PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar420cro.exe','mess.exe');Start-Process 'mess.exe'";
This command downloads and execute the downloaded exe. i have tried to run this command through javascript like this "exec("PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar420cro.exe','mess.exe');Start-Process 'mess.exe'";"
But have not succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. JavaScript doesn't have any method to allow you to download, not to mention *run* an exe.

If it *were* possible, we'd all be incapable of browsing the internet due to the amount of viruses we'd be downloading *and running* involuntarily.

Comment: Not entirely true. ``open.window("file/path/to/file/browser/cant/handle");`` will download the file, but I don't believe there's a way to easily execute something without some serious scripting/browser abuse.

Comment: It won't download the file. It'll, at worst, show you a download confirmation dialog, @Crowes.

Comment: So ``open.window("/path")`` cannot be used like ``<a href="path"></a>``? Last time I linked an ``<a>`` to a .zip file, Chrome chose to download it because it couldn't open it.

Comment: Then you have Chrome set to automatically download files, by default. I've set that to _always_ ask me. Note that even that auto download can not be triggered from code, unless the code is triggered by a user action.

Comment: Can't we do it by calling a powershell/batch script from javascript.?

Comment: You can't call a powershell/batch script from JavaScript, @AsadAli.