# How to start exe file from user's local roaming folder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, appdata

I need to launch exe file form user's local roaming folder. The options that I've are JavaScript, jQuery. I try to search but I found only ActivexObjects and that are only compatible with IE and not working with non-IE browsers.

Any guidance or suggestion will be handy.

Comment: Now let's imagine what would happen if you could do such a thing... Also, there's definitely NO REASON that you **need** to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html

Comment: What you are suggesting is a very serious security threat.

Comment: I am sure windows will complain loudly but allow it if it was user initiated

Comment: A security war is going to begin !

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have the following folder structure:

```
-WebPageFolder
  -index.html
  -file.txt
```

To open file.txt from within index.html, use this code:

```
<a href="file:///file.txt/">Open File</a>
```

Comment: no way, I am allowed to use only javascript type, I am in Dynamics CRM environment

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to launch an exe from a browser, *except* in the situation @Wais described. In that situation, you're asking the operating system to open a *file* and letting it decide which exe to launch to read that file, and even then, it's a file on the web server, not on the client's computer. Perhaps if you give us more detail on the end result you're trying to achieve rather than the (impossible) implementation you're suggesting we can help you more.