# executing a software on a client system using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can anyone tell me how to execute a .exec file from a PHP script in a client system?

I have tried:

```
<?php
$answer = shell_exec("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\DotNet7.exe");
echo $answer."</br>";
?>
```

Nothing is working. It works on localhost but fails online. I need help

Comment: You know the PHP is executed server-side, right? It will only access files on the same server. I doubt this filepath is correct.

Comment: This is fundamentally not possible.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - the user is asking how to execute that on the _client system_ -- I think that's why AlexK states it is not possible.

Comment: never mind @AlexK.and Alexander Nied didn't read the question proberly that's why i've deleted the comment.. Ofcourse a server can't force the client to start up the program..

Answer (score 0):

You need to try do it with JavaScript functions.

checkout this please

[Is it possible to run an .exe or .bat file on 'onclick' in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html)

Comment: Having some javascript run local executables sounds like a recipe for disaster.  And I doubt it's possible.

Comment: I run the exe with js(will double check again) but if the application is own like Zoom you can try to write in registery a url protocol and call your application with this protocol

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so