# Html download and execute from script

Tags: html, download

Is it possible when if you click on a button (in html)
The file downloads and executes without the user clicking anything else but the button?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible, for a lot of good reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run an .exe or .bat file on 'onclick' in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html)