# How to execute a windows form project method from mvc project?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I have one solution and 2 project on visual studio c#.
First project is a windows form project 1 Form and 1 button on it.
Second project is a asp.net mvc project. Index.cshtm has a submit type button.

When I click submit button, I want to send parameters to other project(windows form project) and execute a method(this method on form project) like button1_click

How can I do it?

[SOLUTION]

using window.external.function

[What is the use of window.external?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694341/what-is-the-use-of-window-external)

Comment: You can achieve this by adding a reference to the Winforms project in your MVC project, but if it's the exact same functionality, I would reccommend that you separate the method to a class library that can be referenced by both projects.

Comment: you could look into Microsoft's ClickOnce: essentially you provide a packaged version of your winforms exe on the same webserver that hosts your MVC application and then the user can start the exe from a link. It is possible to pass parameters, but it is not seamless.

Comment: @lars that would run server-side. OP wants to run that from the client browser (ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: some related stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444551/how-to-open-exe-file-on-client-system-in-a-web-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791511/run-exe-from-client-side)

Comment: @dlatikay OP's question can be interpreted both as wanting to run the same functionality through a web project, and as wanting to actually perform a click on a button in a winforms app through an MVC app. Without clarification, we don't know exactly what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Looks like you need to send click event to some application. 
Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899573/click-on-a-button-in-another-application-from-my-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b36d1b7-687b-45ca-9451-cf62ed3eb300/send-data-from-web-form-to-winforms?forum=csharpgeneral) that have been answered

> The easiest solution is using a database.
>
> Create remote database which both web application and windows
>   application can communicate Use timer object to frequently query the
>   database and display new messages are required Complex solution
>   involves creating UDP/TCP connections between applications.
>
> [Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C)