# heroku Open Application to system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I was learning Heroku. I have a program that opens certain apps on requests in python. I have connected my program to Heroku and I wanted that when I or anyone goes to Heroku's link it opens Zoom on their pc.I have used subprocess to obtain this functionality

{`subprocess.call('C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe')`}.

But when I go to that Heroku link I get an error in logs-

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe'

Comment: If there is no other way, please tell me the solution to achieve this

Comment: All this works fine if using ngrok

Comment: ok sorry. i will remove it

Comment: Now any help???Please

Comment: Though sorry for that 'asap'.it wasn't my attention for being rude

Comment: Don't worry was just an adviced, you know there are people all around the world so is better to avoid 'strong' language you never know if someone in their colture is sounds bad. By the way i don't know the answer of your question, I never from an online App make automatically open something from the User's device. However I can tell that the error is because C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe` is not found, Now this I think is because the heroku app is looking within is envirorment and not looking at your device directory.

Comment: Thank you so much. And if you get the solution please post it. I think you are right, Heroku is looking in its own environment and not my device directory and maybe that's why it is showing me this error.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Is not possible to do.

### Long Answer

I researched it a bit, and the most common and probably 'logical' answer found is that is not possible, mainly for security reasons.

- [User RDL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252914/13903942):

> "You can not start/execute an .exe file that resides locally on the users machine or through a site. The user must first download the exe file and then run the executable."

- [User JLopez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5047811/13903942):

> "This assumes the exe is somewhere you know on the user's computer"

---

### Solution

Depending on the Application you are interested, there may be implementation or API that allows you to leverage this and basically they for you go and search for the installed app in the Client's App.

Now, in your case is for Zoom, and it seems that you can achieve this by following Zoom's guide (Official guides are your best friend) [HERE](http://Launching%20Zoom%20from%20a%20web%20browser).

What it says is just to go at:

```
https://zoom.us/join
```

Then the user must provide the Zoom code, then it you press the 'Open Zoom' in the alert box.

So you just need to add a tag like so:

```
<a href="https://zoom.us/join">Open Zoom!</a>
```

**NOTE**: I'am not sure whether this will actually open Zoom in the web or it goes and finds the Zoom app installed in the Client Device, however is for sure a pretty professional way to open the Zoom meeting as it goes through the actual official Zoom screen.

---

### Sources and reference

- [Run EXE from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791511/run-exe-from-client-side)
- [Open an exe file through a link in a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252913/open-an-exe-file-through-a-link-in-a-html-file)
- [How to open .exe file On client system in a Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444551/how-to-open-exe-file-on-client-system-in-a-web-application)