# Is it possible to access WinForm Application from Web Application

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller, web-applications, remote-desktop

I have two projects. One is WinForm Application to use Remote Desktop for our customers, and other one is Ticket System which is MVC Web Application. I want to add a button in one page of my Web Application to direct to Remote Desktop related to that page's information of the customer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible, it is only possible to use winform to access MVC Web Application which can be achieved via WebView2

Comment: If you mean the following scenario: User clicks on a link in a web page, then your application (which is already installed on client) will open and show a Form? Then the answer is yes, it's possible, and it's a [common scenario for some applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445194/3110834). This is the way that some applications like MS Outlook (mailto: url scheme) or MS Team (msteams: url scheme) work.

Comment: You may find this post useful: [Start an application from a URL and get data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445139/3110834). You can get the full source code of the example from GitHub.

Comment: Let me clearify my question. When I click on button(or anything else even which can direct to another app) I want to open my Remote Desktop app where i can control customer's pc.