# how to go to another page when clicking on each dynamically added submit button using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form in which by using javascript and in a while I add content to it.
Denpending on the number of data in database different number of forms are added to the page.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
?>
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
//add some content to the form by reading from database
<div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="print" id="button" value="print"/>
        </div>

    </form>
<?php
}//end while
?>
```

and below I want to redirect to another page when clicked on each "print" button.
But not only it doesn't redirect to another page but also alert just works for the first button.
Below is the code:

```
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
    alert('hi');
    window.location.href = "design_card.php";
        });
</script>
```

how to solve?
jquery, php or javascript solutions are acceptable. other workable solutions, if work, are good.

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: The problem is because you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute. They must be unique. Change the `id` to a `class` instead

Comment: thanks, it worked
how can I open another .exe program when clicked on this button?

Comment: You cannot open local programs through the browser in JS - it would be a massive security flaw if you could

Comment: how about through php?
for example I send the user to another page and that php page does opening the program.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It cannot open anything on the client.

Comment: so I must buy a host, put the program on the host and try openning the program through host?

Comment: No not at all - I'm saying that you cannot run an EXE on the client machine through a web browser without them explicitly installing something on their machine first to associate a file type.

Comment: See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1791748/519413

Comment: after installing on the user's machine, what should I do?

Comment: Redirect the browser to a file with that extension. The browser will download it, then open the program associated with that extension. However like I said, you will need to get the user to install a standalone program on their machine first - which most people with any sense won't do unless they know who you are and trust the content you're giving them.

Comment: just 1 user needs to work with my web application not a lot of users.
so I need to install the software on one machine.
after installing, how can I Redirect the browser for a user to a file with that extension?

Comment: `window.location.assign('yourfile.yourextension')`

Comment: Can I assign any address  in the 'yourfile.yourextension' or just name of the file?
If possible how should the format of the address be?

Comment: You should really do your own research on this. The path can be anything. The important part is that the file extension matches the file association you created in the standalone app your user installed previously.

Comment: thanks so much
the last comment ==> window.location.assign('yourfile.yourextension')
really helped
I don't know how to show my gratitude towards you

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
?>
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
//add some content to the form by reading from database
<div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="print" id="button" value="print"/>
        </div>

    </form>
<?php
}//end while
?>
```

You have created multiple `<input>` element dynamically with duplicate `id` so the better way is to assign a class to them like

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
?>
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
//add some content to the form by reading from database
<div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="print" class="buttonClass" value="print"/>
        </div>

    </form>
<?php
}//end while
?>
```

And then use this `buttonClass` class as a jquery selector like this

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(){
    alert('hi');
    window.location.href = "design_card.php";
});
```

Comment: that's ok but it doesn't go to "design_card.php" page

Comment: @saeeddoozandeh put your code in a document.ready event handler: `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`