# Detecting image URL in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, url, c#-4.0

Is there a way I can detect an image URL, like:

```
http://mysite.com/image.jpg
```

but with other formats as well? I am using C# with .NET 4.0.

Something like

```
bool isImageUrl(string URL){
}
```

**edit** I meant if the URL points to an image. Eg, the URL

```
http://mysite.com/image.jpg
```

**is** a valid image, but

```
http://mysite.com/image
```

is not.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the file suffix or if the object is an actual image?

Comment: I don't think the edit made it much clearer.  Note that http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7deca8ec973c3c0875e9a36e1e3e2c44?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG is a valid image.  Do you also want that to return true?

Comment: I think this link may help you 
[Link 1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228984/a-better-way-to-validate-url-in-c-sharp-than-try-catch

Comment: Your edit is not actually true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send an HTTP request to the URL (using `HttpWebRequest`), and check whether the returned `ContentType` starts with `image/`.

Answer (score 18):

You can detemine it using the `HEAD` method of Http (without downloading the whole image)

```
bool IsImageUrl(string URL)
{
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        return resp.ContentType.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   .StartsWith("image/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that not all servers will handle `HEAD`, and that you should pass `OrdinalIgnoreCase` to `StartsWith`.

Comment: It works only when the image is valid,perhaps a try catch to prevent System.Net.WebException.

Comment: As of .NET 6, `WebRequest` is now considered obsolete. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated. Consider using `HttpClient` instead if you're using one of the newer versions.

Answer (score 3):

You could of course simply check whether the URL ends with a known image file extension. However, a safer method is to actually download the resource and check, whether the content you get actually is an image:

```
public static bool IsUrlImage(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (!response.ContentType.Contains("text/html"))
                {
                    using (var br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        // e.g. test for a JPEG header here
                        var soi = br.ReadUInt16();  // Start of Image (SOI) marker (FFD8)
                        var jfif = br.ReadUInt16(); // JFIF marker (FFE0)
                        return soi == 0xd8ff && jfif == 0xe0ff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        throw;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this will work, I hate to encourage it.  Can you imagine the number of web requests a single application could generate to a bunch of innocent web servers with something like this?  I know we're here to help, but now I feel uneasy about answering this one...

Comment: Huh? What does the WebRequest class have to do with my comment? In any case, yes, I realize that a URI carries no innate meaning.  I am simply commenting on the fact that, while this is a *technically correct* solution, it is not necessarily a *good* or *the* right solution, for the given application.  Consider the case where someone builds an index of a bunch of images.  A single request to a web page with 1000 image links on it thus generates 1000 HTTP requests. Yay. Again, I realize we're just here to answer questions, but the question itself leads me to believe the use will be inelegant.

Comment: It's not any different. I just didn't want to make the same comment on the three posts with the same answer. :P  My issue is not with the method.  I simply chose to put it on your post since it was the best example of the three posts with the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could just check the string with .EndsWith() for each of a set of strings you define.

If you want to know if the object at that URL is *actually* an image, you will have to perform the web request yourself and check the content-type HTTP header.

Even that may be inaccurate, however, depending on the server.

Comment: Wrong.  http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7deca8ec973c3c0875e9a36e1e3e2c44?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: Both can be wrong or right (download all images to check their type?), the problem is in the question itself

Comment: It's as correct as the question allows it to be.  Some older web servers will not have correct MIME type mappings, anyway, especially for jpeg2000, png, and perhaps a few other formats that will end up coming across as application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a `HEAD` type request using `HttpClient` which will allow you to make a conclusion on whether it's an image without having to download the whole thing.

## Example

```
bool IsImageUrl(string url)
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.Send(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url));
    return response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType
        .StartsWith("image/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

## Extra info

I based the solution on [@L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083097/5946094). Consider this as an alternative for .NET 6+, since after that version, the `WebRequest` class is considered obsolete (Source: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated))

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use HttpClient from System.Net.Http rather than

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("https://picsum.photos/200/300");

bool IsTypeImage = res.ToString().Contains("Content-Type: image");
```