# Create image only when url returns image type

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am trying to fetch an image from a url. If image does not exists at that url then that url returns a static html page.

This is the code which I am using to create image

```
img_profile.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("www.someurl.com/xyz.jpg"));
```

img_profile is my image control id.

In case url return static html page, then I want to show static image.

I am creating windows universal app.

Comment: Try by using string parsing, You can get the things from string as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContentType` to Check either it is image or Static html content.

Create a method to check ContentType .

```
public static bool IsValidImage(string url)
       {
           var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
           request.Method = "HEAD";
           using (var response = request.GetResponseAsync().Result)
           {
               return response.ContentType.ToLower().StartsWith("image/");

           }
       }
```

It this method return false then you can show default image.

Comment: Thanks Amit. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

try below code.

your code

```
string url = @"www.someurl.com/xyz.jpg";
if (IsImageUrl(url))
    img_profile.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
else
    img_profile.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("default_image.jpg"));
```

create function that  can check url is for image or not ?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Globalization;

bool IsImageUrl(string URL)
{
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        return resp.ContentType.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   .StartsWith("image/");
    }
}
```

see this question [Detecting image URL in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082804/detecting-image-url-in-c-net)

Comment: Thank You Darshan for your reply but req.GetResponse doesn't work in windows universal app. It has option for GetresponseAsync but again resp.ContentType will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
**BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("www.someurl.com/xyz.jpg"));
if(File.Exists("www.someurl.com/xyz.jpg"))    
{   
            img_profile.ImageSource=bmp;   
}  
else  
{      
           img_profile.ImageSource= new BitmapImage(new Uri("Static image path"));  
}  
I hope it will work...**
```