# How to validate the url using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check that a uri string is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835269/how-to-check-that-a-uri-string-is-valid)

I have a text box where user is supposed to enter a URL , How can I
programmatically figure out the a URL that user has been entered is valid or
not ,If it valid have to process further process else have to enter valid url?

I try this code:

```
string url = textBox1.Text;
if (!url.StartsWith("http://"))
    url = "http://" + url;
Uri myUri;
if(Uri.TryCreate(url,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute,out myUri))
{
    //use the uri here
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Absolute URL name");
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: why not `Uri.TryCreate`?? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx)? or what do you mean by `valid`? reachable (reachable within your vpn, or globally, ...)? or just spec-valid (http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt)?

Comment: as you've added some code: and what is the problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you consider to be a 'valid' url? Does it just have to match a pattern or does it have to resolve to a document/page/resource?

Comment: Use `UriKind.Absolute` for absolute uris.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is from a similar Question
[A better way to validate URL in C# than try-catch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228984/a-better-way-to-validate-url-in-c-sharp-than-try-catch)

```
string myString="http://someUrl";
Uri myUri;
if(Uri.TryCreate(myString,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute,out myUri)
{
    //use the uri here
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didnt check properly

Comment: By use of this code, if i type any content like(afdafasd) it take as valid url onl?