# Run cmd from browser - by JS

Tags: javascript, html, cmd

I want to open cmd window from my web page(HTML). I'm using JS but something is not right because when i press, the function isn't called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function runCmd(command, option)
{
    var char34 = String.fromCharCode(34);
    var wsh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
    if (wsh)
    {
        command = 'cmd /k ' + char34 + wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(command) + ' ';
        command = command + char34 + wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(option) + char34  + char34;
        if (confirm(command))
        {
            wsh.Run(command);
        }
    }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Run!" onclick="runCmd(‘notepad.exe’, ‘%programfiles%\file.txt’);" />
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I saved it as PHP and now i have an error in FF:

```
ActiveXObject is not defined
[Break on this error] var wsh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
```

Thank you!

Comment: In what browser? You are using IE and the page is in a trusted web site, correct? (Or whatever is needed for IE to run such potentially dangerous stuff)

Comment: in IE and FF...Yes,trusted web site.

Comment: And you though that `eval()` was evil...

Comment: Firefox does not support ActiveX: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex

Comment: ohhhh....This is suck. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You will have to basically turn off all of the security features in your browser (which will need to be some variety of Internet Explorer to use ActiveX).

This kind of thing isn't allowed by most browsers, can you imagine if [random person on the internet] could run anything they wanted on your computer just by getting you to visit a web page?

Comment: are you sure that this is the problem? I tried to add `alert("here");` at the beginning and i didn't see the alert.

Comment: On Windows, it is possible to send commands from the browser to other applications using [custom URL protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows).

Answer (score 1):

According to [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript) :

> This object is a Microsoft extension and is supported in Internet
>   Explorer only...

the `ActiveXObject` is only usable inside [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) and only with additional permissions and several warning messages. you might even consider that as it exposes client computers to several security issues, it is not supported by any other browsers.