# Running the Command on Windows Command prompt using HTML button

Tags: html, windows, python-2.7, command, command-prompt

I would like to run the command python abc.py in the windows command prompt when the button on html page is clicked.The python file is located at  C:/abc.py> I would like to know how to code the html page to do this process.Thank you  for the help.

Comment: You want to run "potentially" malicious code on a button click?! This would be a ridiculous security issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215339/run-cmd-from-browser-by-js

Comment: Its just a basic python hello world script.I would like to know if there is any way to do it using html button

Comment: It doesn't matter what script etc it is, it's a browser security issue. Which is why something like `<a href="file:///C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe">Open Me</a>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer is you cannot.  Feel free to let me know otherwise if you find out a way to do it.