# Install an .appx file from a site

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want create a website for my app! I want if press install button (in my site) be installed .appx from "http://mahdisml.tk/first.appx"
How to install an .appx file from a site ? (not in WindowsStore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install WinRT app with Powershell using this cmdlet

`Add-AppxPackage C:\App1_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Test\App1_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU.appx`

You can use only drive file path, network file path is not allowed in above cmdlet.

Unfortunately you can't open Powershell from browser, if you want to know the reason then [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215339/run-cmd-from-browser-by-js).

So conclusion is that it is not possible to install WinRT app in just a click of a button.