# TomTom website opens client software

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, tomtom

I recently received an e-mail about a TomTom map update and clicking through the website appeared to be a 'special link' which opened the TomTom client software when clicking.  Because I'm on a different machine I obviously can't test it, but the anchor link looks like this:

```
<a href="tomtomhome:contentitems-of-type:map">Start TomTom HOME</a>
```

This doesn't look like a normal link - so how does it work?  What do the colons (:) mean?  Does it really allow client software to be opened via a website click?

Comment: Any decent browser will check which software owns "tomtomhome:", and then ask you whether you really want to start TomTom HOME. So it takes two clicks, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part before the double colon is the protocol to handle the url (so here *tomtomhome*). They must have registered this custom protocol when you installed the client software.

More info about registering custom url protocols: [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Comment: it's what before the first :, so http://www.domain.ext has the protocol http. The ftp://www.domain.ext has the protocol ftp, ... This protocol says the browser what it has to use to process the url. In this case it's a custom protocol tomtomhome.