# How to have Parameters like Y! Messenger (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Hi , You've seen the Yahoo Messenger parameters (Like this : **ymsgr:sendim?YahooID** ) certainly ! when you click on it , it will be handled by Y! Messenger application and in this case , a new pm windows will be shown .
what called these parameters ? and How can i use them in my application ?

Thank you

Comment: This has already been asked and answered. Follow the link above this comment.

Comment: Notice that these aren't called *parameters*, but *protocols*, like `http:`, `ftp:`, `mailto:`, etc. You have probably also seen `res:`, `javascript:`, and the others (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767739(VS.85).aspx) a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think that these are called [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Hmm, those are the ones you need to handle URL's like that and feed content to the browser. I believe this question is about links to external programs, much like "mailto:"

Comment: @Stijn: Well, `mailto:` is one of the predefined APP:s, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767739(VS.85).aspx. But really, I have never touch this part of the Windows API.

Comment: I have passed all levels and all registry values have been created but , i got this error : "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address , because the protocol (myapp) isn't associated with any ptogram" . why ?

Comment: @Kermia: If you want to get more attention to your question, you can offer a bounty.

Comment: @Kermia: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties