# URL schemes (Protocol handler) programming for Windows?

Tags: windows, protocols, custom-protocol

[This page](http://www.xmldatabases.org/WK/blog/1154%5FHandling%5FURL%5Fschemes%5Fin%5FCocoa.item) explains how to make a Mac application to handle custom URL schemes. How can I do the same thing with PC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register an application as a URL Protocol Handler, you simply create registry entries telling windows what you want to do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DO you want to write a pluggable protocol handler for Windows Shell and Internet Explorer? If so, check out documentation for URLMon.