# Load program from web procotol

Tags: html, protocols, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL schemes (Protocol handler) programming for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287879/url-schemes-protocol-handler-programming-for-windows)

Let's say I made a program, and I want to access it from out of a webbrowser.

Let's say I have a website. In my site, I put an

```
<a href="myProgram://someParameter">Click here to open my program using this parameters</a>
```

I know this is possible because I saw other tools using it.
Does *this* have any specific name?

My program need to "know" how to deal with this incoming parameters?
What do I do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not opening a random link to see what you mean.  Can you please explain more? Are you saying you want a program that you've written to be opened *and executed* on a client machine via a link?

Comment: are you talking about magnet links?

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are talking about is a magnet link. A lot of torrent websites use them to start downloads.

Comment: Magnet links are just one example for pseudo-protocols. An earlier example are ed2k links.